# Display fallback language, retain selected language

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I've got a multilingual site where English is set as the default and fallback language. Most of the content is translated, but some of it is not. When I access some untranslated content, the fallback English is displayed, however, the site's selected language is also switched to English (so I also get English menus, etc.), so if I would then go to some page which is translated, I would still see English.

Is there a way to tell Drupal "display fallback, but display the menus and other stuff in the non-english language and remember the selected language"?

For the record, each language is in its own directory (not a domain) and language selection is done in this order:

1. List item
2. Selected Language
3. Session
4. URL
5. Account admin pages
6. User
7. Browser

Comment: No answers? :-(

Comment: can you clarify what you want ?  if  user  go to a content that not translated what you want happened to it?

Comment: When I display content which is not translated, the original (English) is displayed. That is actually what I want - what I don't want is all of the translated parts of the page, like menus, etc. to change to English as well. I would like to display the fallback English language of the node, while displaying the rest of the page (menus, etc.) in the local language, so that when I leave the non-translated node's page and move to a translated node, the browser will still remember my local language choice and display that instead of English.